# Configuring Serenity BDD to use Safari with any SSL Certificate

Tags: safari, serenity-bdd, ssl

I am using Serenity BDD for automation testing of four browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari).  I have configured serenity.conf with browser specific configuration for Chrome and Firefox so that these browsers accept invalid SSL certificates during automation testing.   However, when it comes to Safari browser I need to do the same type of configuration, but I cannot figure out how to do this and I can see no related doc.

The underlying Selenium classes seem to support an Accept SSL Certificates option.

Anyone know what this configuration should look like in serenity.conf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems safari doesn't have a driver flag to stop it , you have to execute below javascript command

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;


js.executeScript("CertificateWarningController.visitInsecureWebsiteWithTemporaryBypass()");
```

Comment: Thanks @PDHide, this does not work under Safari 15. I receive a JavaScript Exception "can't find variable CertificateWarningController". Looks like Apple have restricted this option.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/d618r7/get_http_websites_on_safari/f0r3gva/   make sure dev mode is enabled

Answer (score 0):

To configure Serenity BDD to use Safari with any SSL certificate, you can add the following code snippet to your `serenity.conf` file:

```
webdriver {
    driver = safari
    safari.accept_ssl_certificates = true
    }
```

This configuration enables Safari to accept SSL certificates, including invalid ones. The `accept_ssl_certificates` attribute is specific to Safari, and can be used to enable or disable the browser's SSL certificate handling behavior.

You can find more information on configuring Serenity BDD to use Safari with SSL certificates in the Serenity BDD documentation.

As for the practical approach, it is generally recommended to use the Page Object Model (POM) design pattern for automation testing with Serenity BDD. This involves creating a separate class for each web page or component, containing the page-specific elements and methods for interacting with those elements. You can use CSS selectors, XPath expressions, or other locator strategies to identify elements on the page, and the `@FindBy` annotation to link those locators to specific elements in your page object class.

By following this approach, you can create reusable, maintainable, and readable automation tests that are easier to write, debug, and maintain. You can also use properties files or other external configuration files to store your locators and other test data, and refer to them in your page object classes as needed.